# Recommend which site to sell photos? and it is for Spanish-speaking community

Tags: selling

I offer my photos to companies and designers. Know a good place to recommend? Thank you very much!

Comment: Locale-specific questions (i.e. Spanish Speaking) are difficult to answer, and we generally try to avoid them. We prefer to have questions and answers that provide value to the community as a whole, rather than only to a small niche. If you could make your question more general, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose whatever You want from this list:

http://www.istockphoto.com/

http://prostockmaster.com/

http://www.dreamstime.com/

http://www.123rf.com/

http://www.localfoto.co.uk/

http://submit.shutterstock.com/

http://us.fotolia.com/

http://www.bigstockphoto.com/

http://www.featurepics.com/index.aspx

http://www.stockxpert.com/

http://www.pixmac.com/

Comment: Excelent Rafal! thks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't restrict yourself to the Spanish speaking community (although I believe Spanish to have fractionally more native speakers than English, so it's a pretty big audience); Instead look at the picture agencies that operate in your area. I personally use [Alamy](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photography/27375471-EF59-48EC-ADC9-8181E0D15492/1/Rowland%20Shaw.html), and have sold as far afield as the Russian Federation, as well as domestic sales.

If you specifically want to target Spanish speakers, make sure the photographs are correctly keyworded - I'd suggest you add keywords applicable to as many languages as you are fluent, to widen the appeal.

Comment: Thanks Rowland, I think your suggestions are very well!!!Now I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

[istockphoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com) is a pretty widely used [microstock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstock_photography) site and welcomes all kinds of photographers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all the replies. I also found a web site to the Latin Community: http://www.latinstock.com/